# Custom secure store service works only when the All Domain Users group is specified for the members

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, web-services, wcf, secure-store

I created a WCF service that retrieves credentials from the secure store service in SharePoint. I created a target application in the secure store and set the Target Application Type to group. In the members people picker I put my domain account. When I ran the service, it failed. I changed the members to "domain\domain users" and it worked. I changed it again to a security group I am in and it failed again. I am not sure why the target application members has to be all domain users for the service to succeed.

Granted, I am using the secure store in kind of a backwards way. I am not using it to connect to an external source from SharePoint. I am using it as a repository for credentials that I plan on using, for example, in a provider-hosted app. In the app I will call the service, get the credentials, and use them where I need them.

So I am not sure why I need to have the application members set to all the domain users group for the service to work. Any help is appreciated.

I used the following site as a basis for the service:

[Retrieving Credentials from the SharePoint Secure Store using C#](http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.com/2013/10/retrieving-credentials-from-sharepoint.html)

**Edit**: I think I may have discovered my issue. I was running the service's code using elevated permissions:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate (){
     // code
});
```

I took that out it and it seems to work now.